# Most Pythonic way to group and filter a Pandas DataFrame with set_index() already performed at the outermost grouping level?

Tags: python, pandas

For various reasons, I want to process a Pandas DataFrame that has this general structure:

```py
import pandas
exampledf = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'PersonId':'123','Interest':'Basketball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-04-18 13:00:08', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Cake or death?'},
    {'PersonId':'123','Interest':'Baseball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('1999-01-01 09:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Swallow speed?'},
    {'PersonId':'456','Interest':'Swimming','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-02-27 23:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Answer to life, universe, everything?'},
    {'PersonId':'123','Interest':'Basketball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-04-18 13:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'N/A'},
    {'PersonId':'789','Interest':'Racquetball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-02 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Will there be food?'},
    {'PersonId':'789','Interest':'Racquetball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2002-05-28 02:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Swag?'},
    {'PersonId':'789','Interest':'Racquetball','SubmittedDate':datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-02 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'Question':'Good, thanks.'}
    ])
exampledf.set_index(['PersonId','Interest'], inplace=True)
print(exampledf)
```

Hence looks like this:

```
                                                   Question       SubmittedDate
PersonId Interest                                                              
123      Basketball                          Cake or death? 2018-04-18 13:00:08
         Baseball                            Swallow speed? 1999-01-01 09:00:00
456      Swimming     Answer to life, universe, everything? 2011-02-27 23:00:00
123      Basketball                                     N/A 2018-04-18 13:00:00
789      Racquetball                    Will there be food? 2018-05-02 12:00:00
         Racquetball                                  Swag? 2002-05-28 02:00:00
         Racquetball                          Good, thanks. 2018-05-02 12:00:00
```

I want to keep my output in the same structure as my input, but minus any rows that don't have the latest SubmittedDate, breaking ties arbitrarily (first row found is fine).

I've found lots of ways to do it at all *(all sorts of extra stripping and re-adding of indexes)*.  For example:

- I can do `exampledf.reset_index()` before doing a `.groupby()` and then just `.set_index()` again after I'm done, but that seems awkward

But I'm struggling to do this elegantly.  For example:

- I can `.groupby(level=[0,1])`, which adds redundant "PersonId" & "Interest" levels, and that doesn't cause a problem for ".max()", and which goes back to the general look and feel just fine with a `.reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)`, but when I try to squeeze in the `drop_duplicates()` on "PersonId," "Interest," and "SubmittedDate" somewhere in all that, I can't get it to work in a way that doesn't involve more grouping & resetting.

For example, this gives me a `KeyError: 'PersonId'` error:

```py
lastsubmittedperlookuptiesbrokendf = exampledf.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x[x['SubmittedDate'] == x['SubmittedDate'].max()]).reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True, inplace=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['PersonId','Interest','SubmittedDate'])
```

As does this:

```py
lastsubmittedperlookuptiesbrokendf = exampledf.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x[x['SubmittedDate'] == x['SubmittedDate'].max()]).drop_duplicates(subset=['PersonId','Interest','SubmittedDate']).reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True, inplace=False)
```

What is the most Pythonic way to get the following output?

```
                                                   Question       SubmittedDate
PersonId Interest                                                              
123      Baseball                            Swallow speed? 1999-01-01 09:00:00
         Basketball                          Cake or death? 2018-04-18 13:00:08
456      Swimming     Answer to life, universe, everything? 2011-02-27 23:00:00
789      Racquetball                    Will there be food? 2018-05-02 12:00:00
```

(Note that my current clunky implementation re-sorted the interests, but I don't care what order they sort in.)

Answer (score 2):

Since sorting is quick, quick enough it's not worth worrying too much about doing the extra work above just a `max`, one way would just be to sort the SubmittedDate and then take the last after a groupby:

```
In [11]: exampledf.sort_values("SubmittedDate").groupby(level=[0,1]).last()
Out[11]: 
                                                   Question       SubmittedDate
PersonId Interest                                                              
123      Baseball                            Swallow speed? 1999-01-01 09:00:00
         Basketball                          Cake or death? 2018-04-18 13:00:08
456      Swimming     Answer to life, universe, everything? 2011-02-27 23:00:00
789      Racquetball                          Good, thanks. 2018-05-02 12:00:00
```